# If uri and hard drives, to chain file:// in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The name of the variable, is fed from an XML menu, which depending on my selection, download a file from the network or hard drive.
Or the need to do so that if the name starts with http: for example,

```
http://.........com/testo.txt
```

variable name is the same as

```
http://.........com/testo.txt
```

if the name variable is instead

```
C:\Users\ ........................\text.txt
```

must become

```
file:///C:\Users\........................\text.txt
```

Comment: You are assigning... not comparing `nome` to the string.

Comment: I can't follow what this is asking for. Can you give example input and output?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, I hope to explain better:
The variable name, it is supplied by an in xml menu, which depending of my selection, removes a file from the network, or from the hard disk.
Or need to do so that if the variable name begins begins with the string http http: //.........com/testo.txt
while if I select a hard disk files must concatenate the uri files on the hard disk in file: /// .......... /testo.txt otherwise I will not read the file

Comment: Please [edit] your question with new details, that way it is more visible and you have better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (('pao' in nome)):
    # do what you want
else: (('carlo' in nome)):
    # do what you want
```

You're using the `=` operator too, which assigns, rather than checks equality. To check for equality, you should use the `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to get this working on a variable named 'nome'

- First part, check if the string contains "pao":

  ```
  'pao' in nome
  #Examples
  'pao' in 'papao' # True
  'pao' in 'foobar'# False
  ```
- Second part, replace "Carlo" with "pao":

  ```
  nome.replace('Carlo', 'pao')

  #Examples
  "Carlo L.".replace("Carlo", 'pao') # returns "pao L."
  "foobar".replace("Carlo", 'pao') # returns "foobar"
  ```